# Query with equation

Tags: sql, oracle, expression

I have 3 queries that return 3 values. I'd Like to join the queries to perform the following expression:

```
(MgO + CaO)/SiO2
```

How can I do that?

MgO:

```
SELECT sampled_date, result 
FROM AF_VW WHERE element = 'MgO' AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY sampled_date DESC;
```

CaO:

```
SELECT sampled_date, result 
FROM AF_VW WHERE element = 'CaO' AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY sampled_date DESC;
```

SiO2:

```
SELECT sampled_date, result 
FROM AF_VW WHERE element = 'SiO2' AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY sampled_date DESC;
```

Comment: You tagged the question with Oracle, but the title made a reference to SQL Server - which database are you using? (I guessed Oracle based on syntax).

Comment: FYI: in those three sample queries the `ORDER BY` is essentially meaningless.  the ROWNUM = 1 condition is evaluated before the rows are sorted, so you are getting an arbitrary row and then "sorting" it by itself.  If you want the rows with the most recent date, you could (a) use a DENSE_RANK function, (b) use an analytic function as in vkp's answer, or (c) use a nested subquery structure with the ORDER BY in the inner query and the ROWNUM condition in the outer query.

Comment: Your question says that your queries returns 3 values. If so use similar syntax: 
`select ((select 7 from dual) + (select 4 from dual)) / (select 5 from dual) from dual`. Replace queries in brackets with your statements, select result from dual.

Answer (score 2):

```
with x as (
SELECT sampled_date, result, element,
row_number() over(partition by element order by sampled_date desc) rn 
FROM AF_VW)
, y as (
select 
case when element = 'MgO' then result end as MGO,
case when element = 'CaO' then result end as CaO,
case when element = 'SiO2' then result end as SiO2
FROM x where rn = 1)
select (mgo+cao)/sio2 from y;
```

You can use row_number function instead of `rownum` and then select the results for the 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The queries in your question are probably *not* doing what you expect.  Oracle evaluates the `WHERE` clause *before* the `order by`.  So, the following chooses one arbitrary row with `MgO` and then does the trivial ordering of the one row by date:

```
SELECT sampled_date, result 
FROM AF_VW
WHERE element = 'MgO' AND ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY sampled_date DESC;
```

Really, to get the equivalent result, you would need to emulate the same, unstable logic.  Unstable, because the results are not guaranteed to be the same if the query is run multiple times:

```
with mg as (
          SELECT sampled_date, result 
          FROM AF_VW
          WHERE element = 'MgO' AND ROWNUM = 1
         ),
     coa as (
          SELECT sampled_date, result 
          FROM AF_VW
          WHERE element = 'CaO' AND ROWNUM = 1
         ),
     sio2 as (
          SELECT sampled_date, result 
          FROM AF_VW
          WHERE element = 'SiO2' AND ROWNUM = 1
     )
select (mgo.result + cao.result) / sio2.result
from mgo cross join cao cross join sio2;
```

I suspect you really want the most recent sample date, which is what VKP's answer provides.  I just thought you should know that is *not* what your current queries are doing.